# getting unexpected speedtest results in safari

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi recently i have developed a project in angular 5.2.6 for speed test. every thing is fine except 2 issues.

1. when i test it in safari browser it is giving unexpected results of download speed. like 540,430,456,435 Mbps. But it is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla(50,45,56,60 Mbps).
2. its vendors file is too heavy. so it is taking too much time to load.

When i check in console then i get that it took almost 6-8 second in coming the response in chrome/Mozilla but in safari it took .6 to .8 sec.
[here](http://134.119.204.14:4200/) is the link of my application.and
Please help me in resolving my issue.

Comment: How big is your vendor file? Did you compile in regular or AOT mode?

Comment: my vendor file size is 11.6 mb. amd how to compile it with AOT mode. i just type command npm start or ng serve --port portno --host hostname

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you out with your first part, but your second part is solved by building in [AOT mode](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler).

Read through the documentation below, but for a quick response you can add the `--aot` flag to your `ng serve` command to compile it in AOT mode.

[Documentation on Angular serve with the Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve)

[Documentation on Angular builds with the Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

Comment: thanks @Daniel W Strimpel i am trying and let you know the response shortly.

Comment: great @Daniel W Strimpel  it is optimize but only 3 mb. but not enough still vendor file size is 8.4 MB.

Comment: tell me @Daniel W Strimpel any possible solution please

Comment: You will have to look to see what 3rd party libraries are in your vendor bundle besides the Angular stuff.

Comment: how i am going to know the 3rd party library in angular stuff.